# No module names django.core, but I can import django from the shell

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

When I run django in a virtual environment, I get `No module named 'django.core'`:

```
(proj)[jenia@li app]$ python manage.py runserver
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    ImportError: No module named 'django.core'
```

However, when I run the Python interpreter, and import django, there's no error message:

```
(proj)[jenia@li app]$ python
Python 3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 17:23:49) 
[GCC 4.9.0 20140507 (prerelease)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import django
>>>
```

When I import django.core it fails of course.

What am I doing wrong? What could this be related to?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Did u already try to reinstall it again virtual env??

Comment: It seems package path is not set properly

Comment: what does `django.__file__` output from the python shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have no django installed **at all** or you have similar called folder or py-file in current directory.

You can print `django.__path__` and I bet it will point to some script, called `django.py` or package folder `django`, which is not a django.

You should rename it, so `import` will look deeper, to python-packages, where *real* django is located.

Comment: @sof_dff That's a really common problem, even with experienced devs. Glad it helps :)